# JQuery drag and drop into sortable DIV inside the iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

The situation is this: I have draggable elements and need to connect them to a sortable DIV, which is within the iframe.

The code:

**page.html**

```
<div id="draggable">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
</div>

<iframe id="iframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can not change the structure, and I really need to use iframes. I'm trying to follow this example:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

But the target is sortable within the iFrame, and I can not adapt the example to this situation. If anyone has any demo in jsfiddle or any suggestions that might help me, I am grateful!

Answer (score 0):

[Drop elements inside iframe only else revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320455/drop-elements-inside-iframe-only-else-revert)

check the above link...I have managed to drag and drop but there is a little problem with the droppable area.

Comment: I've tried this solution but could not resolve the problem area droppable. :(

Comment: I have started looking for a different way of implementing this...check http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/